# Can any part of Sta"m-making be done by a Gentile?

Tags: gentiles, tefilin, sefer-torah, mezuzah

There are several steps that I can think of that "precede" or are "peripheral" to the actual writing of Sta"m (Sifrei Torah, Tefillin and mezuzot). Can any of these be done by a Gentile?

- Preparation / manufacturing of blank parchment sheets (I'm uncertain of the exact process of how parchment is made. Most likely, it involves numerous steps from the time of getting the skin off the animal until the time that it becomes parchment, including any "glossing" or other finishing.
- Preparation / manufacturing of the ink
- *Sirtut* - drawing rule lines on the parchment
- Sewing parchment sheets together
- Manufacturing *atzei chayim* (wooden "rollers") for Torah
- Placing the *atzei Chayim*

**For tefillin:**:

- Manufacturing the straps including any finishing (polishing, coloring, cutting, trimming, etc.)
- Manufacturing the *batim* - all parts involved including stripping the leather, and shaping the housing, and any finishing, coloring, or polishing, etc.

I may have listed, mainly items that can **not** be done by a Gentile, inadvertently. If there are items that **can** be done by a Gentile that I haven't mentioned, please mention them.

Comment: For mezuzos: the casing is not me’akev, so I assume that a non-Jew can make that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at [R Yerachmiel Askotzky's Tefilin and mezuzos](http://a.co/4EPGW2D) (and checked things with [R Reuvain Mendlowitz' Inside stam](http://a.co/gZSCKWT)). R Askotzky writes there a number of the activities involved in preparing *stam* need to be done *lishma* and therefore can't be performed by non-Jews.

There are however some where *lishma* is not a requirement

- raising the animals
- slaughtering them (they don't need to be *shechted*)
- salting the hides (some *poskim* consider these *mehudar*, others *kosher lechatchilah*, others only *bdieved*)
- soaking the hides in water
- *sirtut* (scoring the parchment) for *tefilin*

Other similarly "physical building activities" need to be done *lishma*, e.g.,

- tanning and painting the hides
- spinning the *gid*
- manufacturing the *batim* (mentioned in R Mendlowitz book)
- *sirtut* (scoring the parchment) for *sefer Torah, megillah and mezuzah*
- writing
- painting *retzuot*
- and more

There will always be *hiddurim* that prefer for some/all these activities to be done by observant Jews.

In all cases, one should note that there are many complex *halachot* governing all these activites. As such, it takes a learned Jew and examiner to be sure all are done according to the law.

Comment: Note this is accd to the Rambam's opinion about Lishmah through gentiles. The Rosh allows gentiles to have Lishmah if a Jew stands over him and tells him to make this object for X. Ashkenazim tend to be more Meikil about this at least when needed. In fact in the last millennium it was very common to use gentiles to make parchment, at least for most of the process